# Infinitely recursive summation of floor function

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions, fractional-part

I'm actually dealing with the fractional part function,

$$\{x\} = x - \lfloor x\rfloor$$

[On Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Continuity_and_series_expansions), a Fourier series expansion is given as,

$$\{x\} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi k x)}{k}$$

However, since $\sin(2\pi n)$ is $0$, we can actually just substitute the fractional part of x on the  inside as well.

$$\{x\} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi k \{x\})}{k}$$

This gives us a recursive definition for the fractional part, as we could just substitute the whole expression inside again,

$$\{x\} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sin\left(2\pi k \left(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(2\pi m \ ...)}{m}\right)\right)}{k}$$

Is there not some kind of trick to use this fact to get a closed-form expression of $\{x\}$ without summing the original infinite series?

Comment: I don't see how this helps... You still have an infinite sum.

Comment: It reminded me of telescoping series, but maybe I'm just off

Comment: Doesn't look telescoping to me. Just looks like it's not evaluatable.

Comment: We can decide this even just without trying the trick: if this did telescope, the function would be a finite sum of sines. Is this the case? Clearly no as the function is not differentiable or even continuous at infinitely many reals.